# how to fix 'keypress with enter key with a checkbox in react js'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have to enable the enter key to check the checkbox in my page for the component checkbox. the event is created and tried the following below code but its not working fine as per the requirement.

```
<div style={{ paddingTop: '0px' }}>
    <CheckBox
        onClick={() => { this.handleClick(); }}
        inlineCBStyle={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}
        name={'edgeTerms' + this.props.line}
        id={'edgeTerms' + this.props.line}

        onKeyPressed={(e) => {
            if (e.keyCode === '13' || e.keyCode === '33') {
            this.edit();
            e.preventDefault();
            }
        }}
        checked={this.state.agreementChecked}
        ariaLabel="payment agreement"
    >
        <span className="caption color_gray_six">{userConsent}</span>
    </CheckBox>
</div>
```

this is component for the checkbox

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import '../../assets/css/common/checkbox.css';

class Checkbox extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="" style={this.props.inlineCBStyle}>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={this.props.id}
              disabled={this.props.disabled}
              className="checkbox"
              value={this.props.id}
              name={this.props.name}
              onClick={this.props.onClick}
              checked={this.props.checked}
              defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked}
              analyticstrack={this.props.analyticstrack}
              aria-label={this.props.ariaLabel}
              tabIndex="0"
              role="checkbox"
              aria-checked={this.props.checked}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.id} style={{ display: 'flex' }}><span className="checkboxOnlySpan"></span>{this.props.children}</label>
          </div>
          {/* <div style={{ padding: '0 0 0 8px' }}>
            <label htmlFor={this.props.id} style={this.props.inlineLBLStyle}>{this.props.children}</label>
          </div> */}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  type: 'checkbox',
  disabled: false,
  children: '',
  name: '',
  onClick: () => (false),
  defaultChecked: false,
  analyticstrack: '',
  ariaLabel: ''
};

Checkbox.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.any,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  defaultChecked: PropTypes.bool,
  inlineCBStyle: PropTypes.object,
  analyticstrack: PropTypes.string,
  checked: PropTypes.any,
  ariaLabel: PropTypes.string
};


export default Checkbox;
```

currently spacebar is checking the checkbox and i want to enable enter key also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onKeyPress` on `input` or `onKeyPressed` directly on `input` instead of passing as props from parent component.

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  _handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
       this.props.handleKeyPress()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="checkbox" onKeyPress={this._handleKeyDown} />
  }
}
```

Using `onKeyPress`

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    onKeyPress={event => {
                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                  this.props.handleKeyPress()
                }
              }}
/>
```

You could pass `_handleKeyDown` from parent component.